# Centering an image and navigation together in the same foundation row?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm building a new site at the moment and decided to use foundation this time round so its responsive from the get go instead of bare bones coding, but having a bit of an issue centering an image and navigation together in a row. They're sitting in the same row together, just not 'equally'.

HTML:

```
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="row fullWidth">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" />
                        </div>
                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array('main-menu' => 'Main Menu'));
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
    float: right;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I imagine its very simple but usually without foundation you just have to set a margin of 0 auto and that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center them each on the same line, you can use `display: table-cell;` on each element and center them vertically with `vertical-align: middle;`. Like this :

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation #logo {  display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }

#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
  display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; 
}

.columns { display: table; width: 100%; }
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7dqygqw/4/)

Comment: Hi Vincent, that didn't center them next to each other on the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Vincent, this did work however it affected the rest of foundation meaning I couldn't use it responsively anymore as the columns were set to 100%. I didn't realise originally before marking it as correct.. Do you have a solution to vertically aligning the navigation in the row without affecting foundation?

Comment: What if you change the selector to `#navigation .columns {}` to target only columns in the nav part ?